# Equivalent of Parallel.For's localInit and localFinally to use in TPL Dataflow blocks when MaxDegreeOfParallelism > 1

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a `TransformBlock<int, int>` that has `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 6`. I have also identified that the `Func<int, int>` that is passed to the block's constructor (to be executed for each posted item) could be logically broken down into an expensive initialization routine and a body that mutates the function's local variables. It would be more efficient if I could refactor the function into a class named `TransformBlockState`, perform the initialization once per concurrent action (just like `Parallel.For`'s `localInit` callback) and then allow TPL Dataflow to ensure that the state is never mutated by more than one item at a time.

**Before refactoring:**

```
Func<int, int> original = x => {
    // method local variables
    // expensive initialization routine to setup locals
    // perform action on local variables
    // potentially expensive teardown
}
```

**After refactoring:**

```
public sealed class TransformBlockState<TIn, TOut> : IDisposable
{
    // instance state

    public TransformBlockState()
    {
        // expensive initialization routine
    }

    public TOut Transform(TIn value)
    {
        // called many times but never concurrently for the same instance
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // tear down state
    }
}
```

Does something akin to the `localInit` (for `.ctor`) and `localFinally` (for `Dispose`) callbacks already exist in the TPL Dataflow library?

I want to avoid having a `ConcurrentStack<TransformBlockState>` (lots of unnecessary locking) and I want to avoid storing the `TransformBlockState` in a `[ThreadStatic]` field (because there's no guarantee the `Task` wouldn't be run on multiple threads (sequentially, obviously) or multiple `Task`s on a single thread (perhaps all blocking on I/O)).

Comment: If _initialization is once per concurrent action... and never mutated by more than one item at a time_ then which part would you like to do in parallel? That said, what you need may be better represented as a pipeline instead of a single block but I'd need to understand what you want to do more clearly.

Comment: OK, a toy example: let's say the initialization sets up an SSL connection and the transform body performs a compute-bound problem. The compute-bound problem is invoked multiple times (once per message), but it's wasteful to re-establish the SSL connection every time. MaxDegreeOfParallelism sets a bound on the number of open SSL connections and parallel compute problems.

Comment: @Jono that's not a good example and probably explains what's wrong. Dataflow is meant to create *pipleines* of communicating blocks. It's equivalent to a Bash or Powershell script where each command reads from the input stream and pushes its results to the output stream. There's no initialization in a pipeline

Comment: @Jono as for SSL connections, what do you mean? HttpClient can be used by multiple threads and *pools* connections. Only the first call is going to establish the SSL channel, all other calls will reuse it. Perhaps what you want is a pool for those expensive resources?

Comment: @Jono infuriating detail. There *is* an ObjectPool, available in the [Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool/) .NET Standard package. No-existent documentation [but the code](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/master/src/ObjectPool) is simple enough and [lock-free](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/ObjectPool/src/DefaultObjectPool.cs)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a stateful block, `TransformBlock` (or `ActionBlock`), you create a function that creates the block and put the state in local variables and capture them:

```
private IPropagatorBlock<int,int> CreateMyBlock()
{
    var state = 0;
    return new TransformBlock<int,int>( x => x+state++ );
}
```

This way, the your class is implicitly created by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't give me one state per concurrent transform/action, it's a single shared state for all transforms/actions executing in the block.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly groups the individual items that are sent into the transform block?

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to `loclaInit` or `localFinally`. You can create a similar behavior with a pipeline of blocks or perhaps use connection pool if that's the expensive initialization. But you may need to reconsider your problem and TPL-Dataflow may not be the best fit. Without knowing more about the exact problem to solve it difficult to say. But typically any one time initialization/per input should be done outside of the flow and passed in.

But like I said you can use a pipeline to get something like `Parallel.Foreach` although it may not really be what you're looking for.

```
public class DataflowPipeline
{
    private TransformBlock<IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<Locals>> Initialize { get; }
    private TransformManyBlock<IEnumerable<Locals>, Locals> Distribute { get; }
    private TransformBlock<Locals, Result> Compute { get; }
    //other blocks, results, disposal etc.


    public DataflowPipeline()
    {
        var sequential = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 };
        var parallel = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 6 };

        Initialize = new TransformBlock<IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<Locals>>(
            inputs => inputs.Select(x => new Locals() { ExpensiveItem = string.Empty, Input = x }),
            sequential);
        Distribute = new TransformManyBlock<IEnumerable<Locals>, Locals>(x => x, sequential);
        Compute = new TransformBlock<Locals, Result>(
            local => new Result() { ExpensiveItem = local.ExpensiveItem, Output = local.Input * 2 },
            parallel);

        //Other blocks, link, complete etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a better example - I need to get a few thousand ticket records from airlines (GDSs actually). To do that, I need to establish an expensive *session* before I can send the SOAP or REST request. Sessions are throttled, so I really don't want to create a new one per ticket. It doubles the time needed per request *and* wastes money and resources.

Creating a custom block would seem like the solution but it's actually *not* that good.
Dataflows establish *pipelines* of processing blocks that work on a stream of messages. Trying to make them work in a different way will clash with they fundamental assumptions of the dataflow model.

For example, Tasks are used for parallelism, throttling and load balancing - the [MaxMessagesPerTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.maxmessagespertask?view=netcore-2.2) option kills tasks after the maximum number of messages are received so that one task won't hog the CPU for a long time. Creating and destroying sessions per task would break that mechanism *and* end up creating more sessions than necessary.

**Pooling**

One way to handle this, is to use an object pool fed with the "expensive" objects that will be used by the blocks, in this case the Sessions. Infuriatingly, the [Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool/) package offers just such a pool. The docs [are non-existent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.objectpool?view=aspnetcore-2.2), they are deceptively placed in the `ASP.NET` tree but that's a standalone, .NET Standard 2.0 package. The Github [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/ObjectPool/src/DefaultObjectPool.cs) is deceptively simple and the class uses Interlocked.CompareExchange to avoid locking. There's even a LeakTrackingObjectPool implementation.

If I knew about this in the past, I could have written :

```
var pool = new DefaultObjectPool<Session>(new DefaultPooledObjectPolicy<Session>());
```

The [DefaultPooledObjectPolicy](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/ObjectPool/src/DefaultPooledObjectPolicy.cs) policy just uses `new` to create a new instance. It's easy to create a new policy though, eg one that uses its own creation logic or even a factory method :

```
public class SessionPolicy : DefaultPooledObjectPolicy<Session>
{
    public override Session Create()
    {
        //Do whatever is needed here
        return session;
    }
}
```

**Redirection**

Another option is to use *multiple* block instances and have the source block to link to all of them. To avoid sending all messages to the first block, a bounded capacity is needed. Let's say we have this factory method :

```
TransformBlock<TIn,TOut> CreateThatBlockWithSession<TIn,TOut>(Settings someSettings)
{
    var session=CreateSomeSessionFrom(someSettings);
    var bounded=new DataflowBlockOptions {BoundedCapacity =1};
    return new TransformBlock<TIn,TOut>(msg=>FunctionThatUses(msg,session),bounded);
}
```

And use that to create multiple blocks:

```
_blocks=Enumerable.Range(0,10)
                  .Select(_=>CreateThatBlockWithSession(settings))
                  .ToArray();
```

The source block could connect to all those blocks :

```
foreach(var target in _blocks)
{
    _source.LinkTo(target,options);
}
```

And then, link all those blocks to the next block. The tricky part here is that we can't just propagate completion. If one of the blocks completed, it would force the next block to complete, even though there are messages waiting in the other blocks.

The solution is to use `Task.WhenAll` and `ContinueWith` to propaget completion to the next block :

```
foreach(var target in _blocks)
{
    target.LinkTo(_nextBlock);
}

var allTasks=_blocks.Select(blk=>blk.Completion);
Task.WhenAll(allTasks)
    .ContinueWith(_=>_nextBlock.Complete());
```

A more robust implementation would check the `IsFaulted` status of all tasks and call `Fault()` on the next block if one of them failed